# aligning div contents vertically in special code (Div as table)

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want to change the v-align of some `divs` that are inside of other `divs`. Please check this image for desired outcome:
[Vertical align in div-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKMpb.png)

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
      <div style="font-weight:bold;" class="divhead">
          <div class="col_5 head">aaa</div>
          <div class="col_25 head">bbb</div>
          <div class="col_10 head">ccc</div>
          <div class="col_15 head">ddd</div>
          <div class="col_15 head">eee</div>
          <div class="col_10 head">fff</div>
          <div class="col_10 head">ggg</div>
          <div class="col_10 head last">hhh</div>
      </div>

      <div class="divrow">
          <div class="col_5">aaa aaa aaa</div>
          <div class="col_25">bbb bbb bbb</div>
          <div class="col_10">P:123<br>E:123</div>
          <div class="col_15">test test test test test test test test </div>
          <div class="col_15">test </div>
          <div class="col_10">ISI</div>
          <div class="col_10"><a href="link.php" title='View Profile'> Link</a> </div>
          <div class="col_10">5555</div>
      </div>

      <div class="divrow">
          <div class="col_5">aaa aaa aaa</div>
          <div class="col_25">bbb bbb bbb</div>
          <div class="col_10">P:123<br>E:123</div>
          <div class="col_15">test test test test test test test test </div>
          <div class="col_15">test </div>
          <div class="col_10">ISI</div>
          <div class="col_10"><a href="link.php" title='View Profile'> Link</a> </div>
          <div class="col_10">5555</div>
      </div>
```

And CSS:

```
.main_div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 0 ; 
    max-width: 1220px;
}

.divhead {
    clear: both;
    max-height:35px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.divrow {
    clear: both;
    background:blue;
    width:100%;
    display: table;
}


.col_1 { width: 1%; }
.col_5 { width: 5%; }
.col_10 { width: 10%; }
.col_15 { width: 15%; }
.col_20 { width: 20%; }
.col_25 { width: 25%; }
.col_30 { width: 30%; }
.col_35 { width: 35%; }
.col_40 { width: 40%; }
.col_45 { width: 45%; }
.col_50 { width: 50%; }
.col_55 { width: 55%; }
.col_60 { width: 50%; }
.col_65 { width: 55%; }
.col_70 { width: 50%; }
.col_75 { width: 55%; }
.col_80 { width: 50%; }
.col_85 { width: 55%; }
.col_90 { width: 50%; }
.col_95 { width: 55%; }
.col_100 { width: 100%; }

.col_1, 
.col_5, 
.col_10, 
.col_15, 
.col_20, 
.col_25, 
.col_30, 
.col_35, 
.col_40, 
.col_45, 
.col_50, 
.col_55, 
.col_60, 
.col_65, 
.col_70, 
.col_75, 
.col_80, 
.col_85, 
.col_90, 
.col_95, 
.col_100
{
    color: #000;
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 0;
    float: right;
    margin:0;
    height:35px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;

}


.head {
    background-color: #069;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height:20px;
}

.divrow:hover .col_1, 
.divrow:hover .col_5, 
.divrow:hover .col_10, 
.divrow:hover .col_15, 
.divrow:hover .col_20, 
.divrow:hover .col_25, 
.divrow:hover .col_30, 
.divrow:hover .col_35, 
.divrow:hover .col_40, 
.divrow:hover .col_45, 
.divrow:hover .col_50, 
.divrow:hover .col_55, 
.divrow:hover .col_60, 
.divrow:hover .col_65, 
.divrow:hover .col_70, 
.divrow:hover .col_75, 
.divrow:hover .col_80, 
.divrow:hover .col_85, 
.divrow:hover .col_90, 
.divrow:hover .col_95, 
.divrow:hover .col_100
{
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
}
```

I want to keep the row highlighting effect. Please help me to fix the code or suggest new approaches.

Comment: Change it how, could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it using diferents ways, but I think the simplest way in your case it's add the property "line-height" on each div (cell) with the same size as the div. then text it's centered.

You can use a wraper div, as mention on this link:

http://techwelkin.com/align-div-center-of-screen-vertically-cross-browser

Comment: Please clarify needed changes. I read many articles and I could not fix aligning. Any change (like using line-height and display:table) results in disordering the table.

Comment: I added this css and no change:   .tabrows {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 background-color:#3C0;
}

.divrow {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
 background-color:#09F;
}

.col_25 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    width: 25%;
 background-color:#F00;
}
.col_15 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    width: 15%;
 background-color:#F00;
}

Comment: try addding a height on the row, and then add text-align with the same size as height

Comment: SOLVED . I changed my codes based on this : http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/using-the-div-tag-to-create-tables.html